# Codeigniter : Index function cannot load

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my controller `index()` cannot load when controller name given in `url`

for example (not load index function as given below):

```
www.example.com/admin  //controller name
```

here the `index()` default load but I can't load it in my controller

other wise (it works when given as below):

```
www.example.com/admin/index  //controller name/function name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `config/routs.php`

**Change this**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

*in addition*

Path - `config/config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = '';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

in your XAAMP Control Panel.

> Go to->Config->php.ini

Replace this

`allow_url_include=on`